# JHipster and Data driven user interface

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, jhipster, data-driven

I have a question on how to use JHipster to create dynamically data driven user interface.

I would like to build a system where

- a Manager can create Type of elements, descripbed with a list of
  property (name,type)
- and then an USER can register a new instance of element by filling
  the associated properties

The UI for the user has to be created dynamically based on the generic properties that have been defined by the Manager.

How can I do this with JHipster / angularjs. Is there any plugin for that? any tutorials? You can see this question has a very generic question: data driven user interface building with JHipster.

Comment: I have contacted danhunsaker that has designed the framework angular-dynamic-forms [1].
It advice is to use [2], have you ever make a protype using this technology?
Is there any JDL file that described the metamodel for generic form?
Do you have any advice on how to do it?

[1]: https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms/issues/80
[2]: https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form

Comment: Perhaps a good link is also the following framework angular2-json-schema-form [3]

[3]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-json-schema-form